# 1d random geometric graphs with curved edges

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am trying to find a good way to draw a 1d random geometric graph, perhaps representing a string of cars on a road, connected in pairs when within radius 1.

One way is

```
RandomGraph[SpatialGraphDistribution[10, 1, 1]]
```

but, essentially, the problem is the edges are indistinguishable:

[image]

One solution is to have the edges curve slightly, so you can distinguish their endpoints. Is there some way to do this? Perhaps using `EdgeShapeFunction`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
RandomGraph[SpatialGraphDistribution[10, 1, 1], EdgeShapeFunction -> "CurvedArc"]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
RandomGraph[SpatialGraphDistribution[10, 1, 1], EdgeShapeFunction -> "CurvedEdge"]
```

> same picture

You can also use `GraphLayout -> "LinearEmbedding"`

```
SeedRandom[1]
RandomGraph[SpatialGraphDistribution[10, 1, 1], GraphLayout -> "LinearEmbedding"]
```

[image]

Comment: Ok that is ideal, thank you.